# Emptying an array doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the weirdest thing I've ever encountered in my programming life.

```
self.walls = new Array();
self.walls = [];
console.log(self.walls); //Doesn't print an empty array, but an array that contains something
```

How is this possible? I set `self.walls` to an empty array in two ways, and it's still full of objects! I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Edit: also, this is the only `console.log()` in the entire script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` does not store the state of the object at the time of calling.

At a later point, you've overwritten the `self.walls` property, which is shown in the console.

If you want to log the true state at the time of executing, you can serialize the object:

```
// Works for primitives only:
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.walls)));

// When the array contains another object, the shown referenced object might
//  change
console.log(self.walls.concat()); // Or any other array-copying method.
```

Comment: That's very strange. Why is it so? So it doesn't pause the execution of a program?

Comment: Depends on the implementation. `console.log` is *supposed* to take a string argument and print the string in the console.

Comment: @Bane It doesn't pause the execution. I have added two methods to print the actual state of the array. If you want to pause the execution, add a [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement.

Answer (score 0):

An array has a `length`, it has methods such as `map`, `shift`, `unshift`, `pop`, `push` and so on, and all of these show up in the console because they are properties of the array.

You probably don't see any property named `0`, `1`, or any other number, right? Those would be the actual array elements, if you'd defined any.

Comment: Yes, I see elements. A tonne of them, actually. Also, this isn't really an answer...

Comment: It explains what you're seeing. A screenshot might help, but you should not be seeing any elements with a numeric key.

Comment: See @Rob's answer above--he is actually seeing elements because `console.log` doesn't pause execution.

Answer (score 0):

As [Rob W explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762189/31671), the `console` sometimes does not show the true representation of the array when it is called.

However, you mentioned *emptying an array* but your code ...

```
self.walls = new Array();
self.walls = [];
```

...is **not** emptying the array. It is assigning a new empty array to the property. To empty the array, you can use...

```
self.walls.length = 0;
```

Comment: @Bane Depends. Do you have other references to that array. If so, the array could not be GC.